# What is the alternative in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, format, string-formatting

I found how to change the locale format in Java, but I want to use it in C#.

This is the (Java) line of code

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%f", floatValue)
```

Comment: See: [`String.Format` which takes a `IFormatProvider` (implemented by 'CultureInfo`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: My question could be duplicate but it has a different and good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Culture you can Use

```
CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

and for Formatting Float with Culture you can use

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-Us"), "{N2}", floatValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

C# equivalent is (simple to string conversion)

```
 String result = floatValue.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Or (formatting)

```
 String result = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0}", floatValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default in  .Net if you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` it is associated with the English language `en-US`
or  you can explicitly  set `CUltureInfo`

```
float value = 16325.62015;   
// Display value using the invariant culture.
Console.WriteLine(  value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Display value using the en-US culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```